# How can I add an axis line on zero on a histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have my histogram, plotted with:

```
def hist_plt(data):
    counts, bins = data.clip(-.5, .5) |> np.histogram$(bins=100)
    plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts, alpha=0.3)
```

(python coconut syntax)

It's producing a chart like this:
[image]

How do I get it draw a nice line up from zero to the top, in the middle?

As an added bonus question, is there some kind of interactive charting library these days that supersedes matplotlib?

Comment: just `plt.axvline(0)`

Comment: Your bonus question (although not suitable for stackoverflow): it strongly depends on your requirements. Bokeh and plotly are used a lot to create interactive pages in Python, but that interact via a webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [vlines](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html):

```
def hist_plt(data):
    counts, bins = data.clip(-.5, .5) |> np.histogram$(bins=100)
    plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts, alpha=0.3)
    plt.vlines(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=1)
```

As for an interactive alternative to matplotlib, perhaps try [bokeh](https://bokeh.org/) or [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/).

Comment: This actually didn't work; but @JohanC's answer above `plt.axvline(0)` did.